# Mathematical operations on list of tuples containing integers and floats

Tags: python, list, tuples, element

This is a follow up of my previous question where I forgot one part of my problem. I have the function below which aims to add elements from one list into another until the list is only 0's. The function works as intended and could probably use some optimisations but that's something I'll try later.

My current problem is that I have to somehow keep the function working as it does but instead of calculating values with the floating point numbers in the list, I need to do so with the floating point numbers in the tuples in the lists. For some background information, the int in the tuple is the processID (this code will run in a multiprocessing project) and the second value is a simple float calculated from various functions.

The lists should look something like this as an example:

```
example_list = [(12345, -0.561432), (23456, -0.861423)]
```

Here is the function as a working code with example lists containing only floating point numbers (not tuples like I need).

```
def cancelOut(deficit_list, trade_1_list, trade_2_list):

    lengths = [len(deficit_list), len(trade_1_list), len(trade_2_list)]
    # List of the lists of positive values
    positive_lists = [trade_1_list, trade_2_list]

    if(len(deficit_list) != 0): # Check deficit_list isn't empty

        total_positive = lengths[1] + lengths[2]
        current_positive = 0

        # Set all indexes to 0 to start
        deficit_list_index = 0
        trade_index = 0
        trade_lists_index = 0

        # While new_deficit_list contains a value different from 0 do the following
        while not all(value == 0 for value in deficit_list):
            # Determine the difference between the current deficit_list value and current positive value of the current list
            value = deficit_list[deficit_list_index] + positive_lists[trade_lists_index][trade_index]
            if(value > 0):
                positive_lists[trade_lists_index][trade_index] = value
                deficit_list[deficit_list_index] = 0
                deficit_list_index += 1
            elif(value == 0):
                deficit_list[deficit_list_index] = 0
                positive_lists[trade_lists_index][trade_index] = 0
                deficit_list_index += 1
                trade_index += 1
                current_positive += 1
            elif(value < 0):
                deficit_list[deficit_list_index] = value
                positive_lists[trade_lists_index][trade_index] = 0
                current_positive += 1
                if(trade_index == (lengths[trade_lists_index + 1] - 1)):
                    trade_index = 0
                    trade_lists_index = 1
                else:
                    trade_index += 1

            if(trade_lists_index == 1 and current_positive == total_positive):
                break

    return [deficit_list, trade_1_list, trade_2_list]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deficit_list_values = [-0.246497, -0.341068]
    positive_values_1 = [0.022148, 0.212573, 0.100531]
    positive_values_2 = [0.281474]
    lists = cancelOut(deficit_list_values, positive_values_1, positive_values_2)
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        print(lists[i])
```

I feel that the issue I'm running into is the fact that the tuples contain floats and ints.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command (native to python 3)

```
list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*list_of_tuples))
```